# Why typing React Routes manually is not working, it redirects to another page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

This is my App.js class. It's connected to Redux Store.

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.checkLocalStorageIfTokenExists();
  }

  render() {
    let routes = null;
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      routes = (
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} />
          <Route path="/details/:countryId" component={CountryDetails} />
          <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
        </Switch>
      );
    } else {
      routes = (
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
          <Route path="/register" exact component={Register} />
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
      );
    }
    return routes;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.authReducer.idToken !== null
  };
};

const mapDispathToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    checkLocalStorageIfTokenExists: () => dispatch(checkLocalStorage())
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispathToProps)(App));
```

When I log in it redirects me to "/dashboard" which is perfect and all other routes are working as they are expected. But when I manually type the URL in the browser (ex: http://localhost:3000/settings) it redirects me to "/dashboard". I understand that when I manually type the URL the entire app is downloaded again and if I'm not wrong Redux store also is built again.

Note: checkLocalStorageIfTokenExists() method simply checks localStorage and changes the Redux LoggedIn state (initializes the token).

So my question... is there any way that I can type the URL manually and go to that page?

Comment: I tried creating a sandbox for the same,it seems to be working perfectly fine,on manually entering the route, it renders the particular component. https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-routerissue-onpgaeload-zvgm6

Comment: Thanks for your help, but if you add authentication then you will understand what I meant above. Let say, if you'r authorised , then you can not get to /settings route manually.

Comment: You simply return null if authorised is false. Try to divide it into 2 conditions(true, false) and separate the routes for both of them.